# When rolling initiative for DM-controlled creatures, does their Dexterity modifier apply?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, ability-scores, npc, initiative

When the DM is rolling initiative for its monsters, does their Dexterity modifier apply, or does the DM just roll a d20 on its own?

Comment: I’ve rolled back to revision 4 where you added the tag, your later revisions were a completely different question, I would recommend posting that question as a new question post.

Comment: We should maybe have asked for it previous, but maybe just for questions going forwards: what have you done yourself to resolve this? Where have you looked and not found an explanation and/or what explanations have you found but which have failed to resolve this for you?

Comment: That said, I think your second question should be wholly covered by: [How do I handle initiative and turns for a group of monsters?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138850) (if not, you're free to ask a new question which explains why)

Answer (score 10):

### Their Dexterity bonus applies

The rule on [initiative](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Initiative) (PHB, p. 189) is not player-specific:

> Initiative determines the order of turns during combat. When combat starts, **every participant makes a Dexterity check** to determine their place in the initiative order.

"Every participant" includes monsters and NPCs, too.

Comment: What if it's a group of monsters/NPCs?

Comment: @BennyS. Please clarify your question first, by adding the tag of the game version you play, for example dnd-5e, if you play fifth edition D&D. This qeustion would be a new question, although with only my answer, I would be OK if you expanded your question to include it. But currently the question is closed, and without you helping us by clarifying, there is little I can do to help

Comment: @BennyS. as Eddymage quotes in his answer below, identical creatures all go on the same initiative. So, if you had, for example, 3 goblins and an ogre, the DM rolls one d20 for the goblins, and adds +2 for dex - all of the goblins act on that initiative count. The DM rolls a separate d20 for the ogre, subtracts -1 for its dex, and the ogre acts on that count

Answer (score 4):

### The rules for initiative are the same for all the creatures involved in a fight.

The rules for rolling [initiative](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Initiative) read (emphasis mine):

> Initiative determines the order of turns during combat. When combat starts, **every participant makes a Dexterity check** to determine their place in the initiative order. **The DM makes one roll** for an entire group of identical creatures, so each member of the group acts at the same time.

Since the [initiative roll](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Initiative) is a Dexterity [check](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#AbilityChecks), it means that even the creatures controlled by the DM roll a d20 and add their DEX modifier: this roll is made by the DM.

As a confirmation of that, in the section on [combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#Combat) in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (page 247), there is no different rule for rolling initiative for DM-controlled creatures (emphasis mine):

> This section **builds on the combat rules in the *Player's Handbook*** and offers tips for keeping the game running smoothly when a fight breaks out.

After that paragraph, there is some guidance about how to track initiative.

---

Anyway, the DMG (page 270) presents some [variants to determine the initiative](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#InitiativeVariants) at the start of a combat. For example, one is called ["Initiative Score"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#InitiativeScore):

> With this optional rule, creatures don't roll initiative at the start of combat. Instead, each creature has an initiative score, which is a passive Dexterity check: 10 + Dexterity modifier.

With this variant, there is no d20 roll to be made.